# Why is Photos using my battery for Audio like this?

Tags: iphone, photos, battery

My new iPhone 7 (which I set up as a new phone and not from a backup) is reporting strange battery usage due to Photos.

It's saying that 15% of the battery has been used in the last 24 hours due to photos being onscreen for 5 minutes, using Audio!

What's happening?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why did you feel the need to quote photos?

Comment: So it was clear that I wasn't casually referring to the act of taking/looking at photos, and instead specifically to the photos app. have you got any answer on this?

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious that your photos app is being involved in some sort of iCloud activity?

Comment: Nah checked that, it's all synced up unforch

Comment: Could it be creating "memories" (those videos or slideshows or whatever that are new in iOS 10)?

Comment: That's a overall percentage it doesn't mean that is it's current usage % rate

Comment: I have seen this on my device where it uses a large amount of battery (and the device itself becomes extremely warm). As I recall, though, in my case it showed the correct usage time of something like an hour of background activity. My guess is it was processing photos for People or Memories. @NoahL

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you have been watching some of your own videos in the photos app. It doesn't mean that the photos app has been doing this for the full five minutes, it just means that there has been audio playing in that app at some time, and the rest of the time could be other things.

Answer (score -1):

If you have iCloud Photo Library turned on, it'll try to download all of your pictures.

Comment: You didn't answer the part where "using Audio", and it usually downloads pictures in the background, not only on screen.